# How do I use move-semantics to reallocate resources from class constructor?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, c++14, move-semantics

To enable me to read a binary file I have made this class. I would like to not copy a temporary for which I am trying to use move semantics. But this code produces "access violation error".

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

class myClass
{
public:
    std::istream& myStream;
    static myClass create(const char* path);
    myClass(myClass&&) noexcept = default;
    myClass(std::istream& input);
    myClass() = default;
};

myClass myClass::create(const char* path)
{
    std::ifstream input{ path, std::ios::binary | std::ios::in };
    if (!input.is_open()) throw std::runtime_error("Error - couldn't open file");
    return std::move(myClass(input));
}

myClass::myClass(std::istream& input) :
    myStream(input)
{

}
int main()
{
    const char* path = R"(file.bin)";
    myClass cr{myClass::create(path)};

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        cr.myStream.seekg(i);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the `create` function the `input` variable is a *local* variable. Its life-time ends with the function, leaving you with an invalid reference. Create the stream in the object instead (i.e. pass the file-name to the constructor, and let the constructor open the file).

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand the use-case for a separate `create` factory function here. What is its purpose? What problem is it supposed to solve?

Comment: `std::istream& myStream;` cannot possibly work. References do not magically enable automatic care-free resource management. You need to decide what you want your class to be. Should your class **own** the stream (alone or in a shared ownership)? Should it **borrow** the stream from somewhere? Should it be able to do either in different situations? Move semantics was invented to optimise classes that own resources. It is meaningless for a class that doesn't own anything.

Comment: `return std::move(myClass(input));` What is the reason for using `std::move` here? Are you aware that it actually hinders copy elision? Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/bKf58EaPY.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the stream after the temporary has been destroyed. You need to store the stream in the myClass object:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

class myClass
{
public:
    std::istream& myStream;
    static myClass create(const char* path);
    myClass(myClass&& other) noexcept;
    myClass(std::istream& input);
    myClass() = default;
};

myClass myClass::create(const char* path)
{
    std::ifstream input{ path, std::ios::binary | std::ios::in };
    if (!input.is_open()) throw std::runtime_error("Error - couldn't open file");
    return std::move(myClass(input));
}

myClass::myClass(myClass&& other) noexcept :
    myStream(other.myStream)
    {
    other.myStream = std::cin;
}

myClass::myClass(std::istream& input) :
    myStream(input)
{

}
int main()
{
    const char* path = R"(file.bin)";
    myClass cr{myClass::create(path)};

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        cr.myStream.seekg(i);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you changed in your code? Why did you make that change? How does the change solve the problem the OP is having? Please take some time to read about [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This doesn't work at all. Have you tried to compile it? `other.myStream = std::cin;` is illegal.

Comment: Unfortunately, this update doesn't solve the issue and produces the same access violation error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the lifetime of `input` in `myClass::create()`. As JensenMcKenzie mentioned, it will be destroyed at the end of that function, and therefore the *reference* passed to the returned `myClass` object will be a dangling reference. The only way to keep the `myClass::create()` function would be to store a concrete `std::ifstream` object inside `myClass`:

```
class myClass
{
    std::ifstream myStream;
    ...
};
```

To allow another `std::ifstream` to be passed to the constructor, it has to be as an r-value reference:

```
myClass::myClass(std::ifstream&& input): myStream(std::move(input)) {}
```

And then you can write the `create()` function like so:

```
myClass myClass::create(const char* path)
{
    std::ifstream input{ path, std::ios::binary | std::ios::in };
    if (!input.is_open()) throw std::runtime_error("Error - couldn't open file");
    return std::move(input);
}
```

Note that you could also just have written a constructor that takes a pathname as an argument:

```
myClass::myClass(const char *path):
        myStream(path, std::ios::binary | std::ios::in)
{
    if (!input.is_open())
        throw std::runtime_error("Error - couldn't open file");
}
```

And then you could have written this in `main()` instead:

```
const char *path = ...;
myClass cr(path);
```

This way no moves are necessary at all.